# Not receiving information when using GET method, only when I don't use it

Tags: python, django

In my project I'm displaying JSON conversations for a certain ID,the ID is passed as an argument in the URL.

```
def conversationview(request, convo_identification):
    data = InputInfo.objects.all()
    conversation_identification = request.GET.get('convo_identification')
    #conversation_id = {'conversation_id': []}
    header = {'conversation_id': '', 'messages': []}
    entry = {}
    output = {}

    for i in data:
        if str(i.conversation_id) == conversation_identification:
            header['conversation_id'] = i.conversation_id
            entry = {}
            entry['sender'] = i.name
            entry['message_body'] = i.message_body
            entry['date_created'] = str(i.created)
            header.get('messages').append(entry)
            output = json.dumps(header)
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

URLs.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^message/', sendMessage.as_view(), name='message'),
    url(r'^conversations/(?P<convo_identification>\d+)', views.conversationview, name='conversationview'),
]
```

`conversation_identification = request.GET.get('convo_identification')` doesn't work (nothing displays on the screen), but when I change it to `conversation_identification = convo_identification` it will display the information for that ID fine. I don't have any HTML for this because I don't need it. But I'm wondering why I can't use request.GET or request.get.GET()? Does it matter? I know by looking at my terminal that there is a GET request being made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django is resolving the **convo_identification** variable as a URL parameter, not part of the request object. The value is set as an argument when the views.py is referred by the urls.py.

When you try to get the **convo_identification** from the request.GET dictionary, it doesn't exist so there is nothing to return with the get method. This will not cause an error but silently set a null value.

To verify that there is no key in your request.GET dictionary that matches **convo_identification** you can print the contents of the request.GET dictionary:

```
print(request.GET)
```

Also the since the variable is initialized when the view is reference, there isn't really a need to re-declare the variable unless you are just changing the name.

Comment: Ah I see, is that because the URL isn't making a GET request then? Because in the terminal it does say GET

Comment: Well...when you load the view you are making a GET request; however, your variable is passed in the path as a URL parameter not the extra data that comes along with other possible GET requests (i.e. a search bar's parameter). I'm sorry if that confused you more...

Comment: No it doesn't thank you for the reply. It's just that I usually send requests through the HTML template. But I don't need HTML for this. Someone gave me this challenge to do with the requirement that 'conversations/<conversation_Id> accepts an HTTP GET action. Does this fulfill that requirement?

Comment: I think the easiest way to think of it is like a POST request:
When you submit a POST request to the view, you have to address it to a URL that is expecting that request. Part of that URL may have a variable or URL parameter in its URL path. However, when you submit a POST...there is a ton of other data that isn't shown in your URL. That is because it is part of the request.POST dictionary.

Comment: Wait you said im not getting the data from the search bar parameter, but the data I need does display when I enter a certain argument into the search bar

Comment: I couldn't exactly say if this would fulfill that requirement. In my opinion it sounds like they want you to pass the data in the request.GET dictionary. That would allow you to pass data to and from the view without needing to reload the page (i.e. AJAX & JsonResponses). However, by technicality you are making a GET request and passing the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165390/discussion-between-wrabbit-and-amon).

Answer (score 1):

You will get `convo_identification` directly from the `Scope of the function`, You don't need to access `request` object to access an url parameter.
 So, Change the line
 `conversation_identification = request.GET.get('convo_identification')` **to** `conversation_identification = convo_identification` will solve your problem :)